# Unix email command is not working

Tags: email, unix

I'm trying to send an email as below from unix environment.once i enter the command it does nothing and i have to kill the process manually.am i missing something here? i believe body is optional.

```
mail -s "Testing" user@mail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it *will* appear to do nothing, it's waiting for you to type in the body of the email before sending it.

From the BSD `mail` man page (though they're all pretty similar):

> **Sending mail**
>   To send a message to one or more people, mail can be invoked with arguments which are the names of people to whom the mail will be sent. You are then expected to type in your message, followed by a 'control-D' at the beginning of a line.

So simply use the end-of-file input sequence <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> (rather than the <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> break sequence) to end the input and send the email.

Alternatively, try:

```
echo '' | mail -x "Testing" user@mail.com
```

or:

```
mail -x "Testing" user@mail.com </dev/null
```

where the two methods of providing empty input effectively do the same thing, without you having to type anything.

Comment: I tried with an attachment,i got this error:
-bash-4.1$ uuencode -m listing|mailx -s "Testing" user@mail.com
-bash: uuencode: command not found
Null message body; hope that's ok

Comment: @BernadAli, not really, since it means your attachment wasn't attached. In addition, you need _two_ occurrences of `listing` if you want to send the file, one to specify the file to read, the other to name the file in the uuencode output. uuencode with one argument simply reads stdin. But first, of course, you need to find uuencode :-)

Comment: ,i did like this,why it is still saying command not found:

-bash-4.1$ uuencode input -listing output -listing|mail -s "Testing" user@mail.com
-bash: uuencode: command not found
Null message body; hope that's ok

Comment: @Bernad, it appears you have no uuencode command in your path. You will see this if you just enter `uuencode` on its own. That's a totally different issue (and unfortunately not a programming one). You need to get it installed with `apt-get`, `yum`, `zypper` or whatever repository manager your distro uses. Or, if it _is_ installed, you need to modify your path to find it.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo, yes you are right,uuencode is not installed, I'll follow as you said.